# How to send model's properties using Kendo.Button()'s Events method to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have a `Kendo.Button()` that invokes a `Javascript` function. That function makes an `Ajax` call to a controller and sends Model's properties to the controller's method:

This is a button:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
                        .Name("btnSubmit")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" })
                        .Content("Submit")
                        .Events(e => e.Click("DisplayData"))

)
```

This is my JavaScript function:

```
function DisplayData() {

    $('#win_wnd_title').text('My Title');

    var id = '@Html.Raw(Model.ID)';
    var amount = '@Html.Raw(Model.Amount)';
    var desc = '@Html.Raw(Model.Description)';

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/MyController/MyMethod/",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: id, Amount: amount, Desc: desc }),
            success: function (result) {
                var dialog = $("#win").data("kendoWindow");
                $("#dataWin").html(result);
                dialog.open();
            }
        })
}
```

I have several pages that will have similar functionality of creating a `Kendo.Button()` and calling javascript.

In one case, I will need to send some parameters to a function, in another I do not.

What I want to do is to have a single javascript function, defined on the `Site.js` file, instead of having creating it a few times on different pages.

So, some pages will have a button sending parameters to a function, some pages will not.

If there is a way to do it, how can I call the function from the `Kendo.Button()` definition using `Events` property and use it in my `Site.js` file?

Comment: you can have a common function which takes an object as parameter so you can do method({ ID: id, Amount: amount, Desc: desc }) or method(null)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that approach

Comment: You will probably want to pass the success callback function as well.

Answer (score 3):

After some research I found a solution:

To pass parameters to  a JavaScript function when using Kendo.Button() we can use `HtmlAttribute` property of the button in the following way:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("btnButton")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", param1= "MyParam1", param2 = "MyParam2")
                    .Icon("k-icon k-i-file-txt")
                    .Content("View Details")
                    .Events(e => e.Click("JavaScriptFunction"))

        )
```

Here, I'm passing title and url as parameters to JavaScriptFunction.

In the function, in order to get the value of parameters use the following logic:

```
var param1 = this.element.attr("param1");
```

That will take care of this.

Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass a function that calls the common function with the parameters:

```
.Events(e => e.Click("function() { JavaScriptFunction('MyParam1', 'MyParam2') }"))
```

Comment: So, if my parameter is coming from Model, I can simply do the following: `.Events(e => e.Click("function() { JavaScriptFunction('Model.Property1', 'Model.Property2') }"))`?

Comment: Yes. but you should use Model outside of the string in order to be evaluated:
`.Events(e => e.Click("function() { JavaScriptFunction('" + Model.Property1 + "', '" + Model.Property2 + "') }"))`

Comment: Thank you. Nice to know another approach